# passing data with intents

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

Lately I have been playing around with intents and bundles. I thought I had them figured out, but I keep getting problems when passing data between intents I understand that you have to use bundles, but when I try implement a simple program to test this, I keep getting a null pointer exception. The program I made is just an activity which calls a service to create a string and then that activity should be able to get the string created by the service and toast it. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, cheers to anyone that can help. Here is the code below

Activity class

```
MyIntent = new Intent(this, GetLocation.class);
startService(MyIntent);

bundle = MyIntent.getExtras();  
test = bundle.getString("location");
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = test;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Service class

```
  Intent Int1 =new Intent(this,MapMock.class); 
   Bundle  b = new Bundle();
   String yeah = new String();
   yeah = "hello";
   b.putString("location", yeah);
   Int1.putExtras(b);
```

Comment: It is not clear how or when the above code is running and where the error is occurring.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/17/android---passing-data-between-activities.aspx

Comment: You need to receive the data in Service class from Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services don't work this way.

The intent you send to the service via startService doesn't get updated and returned to the activity that starts it.

I think you need a bound service.
Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) to find out more. This allows you to call functions and pass values back to the activity.

Comment: Thanks mcnicholls I wasn't aware of bounding services it was just the thing I need as well thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are accessing intent date which you haven't put into intent,

like if you are starting activity from your service, and passing some data use:

```
Intent myIntent=getIntent();
bundle = MyIntent.getExtras();  
test = bundle.getString("location");
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = test;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```